# Change putty settings using scripts

Tags: scripting, putty

Is there any way to save the PuTTY output to a file using the command line? I know this is easily done using the GUI but in my case it has to be done automatically.

What I'm working on:

User clicks batch file -> starts PuTTY, automatically connects to my device over SSH and runs a bunch of commands -> PuTTY should save the output to a file.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by changing registry settings.
Entry point for you is to check what and where is stored for putty:

run regedit and go to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SimonTatham\PuTTY

you can export settings to file by:

```
regedit /e "%userprofile%\desktop\putty-registry.reg" HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Simontatham
```

From here,edit putty-registry.reg to your needs and import on user machine.